# PHP Codeigniter - image manipulation - using GD2

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-manipulation

I'm using the standard `Codeigniter` image manipulation library to resize images, i setted up to use `GD2` library in params.

But the images are very low quality once resized mantaining ratio of the image, i tryed setting up `quality = 100` but they still be in slow quality resized.

What do you use as library to get the best quality images?

I red about `ImageMagick` but i can't install it locally, i need some other way, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a huge fan of [Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine), it's an Image manipulation library for PHP 5.3 inspired by Python's PIL and other image libraries.

It has drivers for GD, Imagick, and GMagick so you should be good to just use the GD implementation.

Here's a [nice presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/avalanche123/introduction-toimagine) and [supporting documentation](http://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick can be installed locally, I used it recently for a project when converting pdf files into images then re-sizing them.

This may also [help you](http://www.elxsy.com/2009/07/installing-imagemagick-on-windows-and-using-with-php-imagick/)

Comment: thanks dude but i'm on macosx and actually i can't install it